# Function to check if input string is an integer or floating point number?

Tags: c

Is there a function in C to check if the input is an `int`, `long int`, or `float`?  I know C has an `isdigit()` function, and I can create an `isnumeric` function as follows:

```
int isnumeric( char *str )
{
    while(*str){
        if(!isdigit(*str))
            return 0;   
        str++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

But I was wondering how to create a function that would take a floating point number (as a string) and output a TRUE/FALSE value.

Comment: you can detect  '.' character to determine if its floating point number

Comment: Is `42.00000000000000000000000000` a floating point number or an int? And `42.00000000000000000000000001`?

Answer (score 13):

This should do it.  It converts the string to floating point using [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) and checks to see if there is any more input after it.

```
int isfloat (const char *s)
{
     char *ep = NULL;
     double f = strtod (s, &ep);

     if (!ep  ||  *ep)
         return false;  // has non-floating digits after number, if any

     return true;
}
```

To distinguish between `float`s and `int`s is trickier.  A regex is one way to go, but we could just check for floating chars:

```
int isfloat (const char *s)
{
     char *ep = NULL;
     long i = strtol (s, &ep);

     if (!*ep)
         return false;  // it's an int

     if (*ep == 'e'  ||
         *ep == 'E'  ||
         *ep == '.')
         return true;

     return false;  // it not a float, but there's more stuff after it
}
```

Of course, a more streamlined way to do this is to return the type of the value and the value together.

Comment: Or implement isint() in similar fashion and then, at the end of isfloat, use `return !isint(s)` instead of `return true`.

Comment: Note that `strtod()` skips leading white space; so does `strtol()`.  You could decide you don't want that by checking that the first character is not white space explicitly.  Alternatively, it would be symmetric to allow trailing white space instead of demanding that the string ends at the end of the number.  These are design decisions, not bugs in the code shown.

Comment: The end-pointer ep would be equal to s if conversion was not performed, e.g. on a pure alphabet string. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof. I have used this fact in my real use cases.

Comment: This is true for plain c too (if one does not trust the C++ reference for plain c) https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod

Answer (score 0):

```
int isnumeric( char *str )
{
    double d;
    return sscanf(str, "%lf", &d);
}
```

Comment: warning: format ‘%g’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 3 has type ‘double *’

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find the data type a given string can fit in, you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>

/* If a floating-point number is +/- F_EPS from an integer,
   consider it to be an integer */
#define F_EPS 1e-7

enum datatype {
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_LONG,
    TYPE_FLOAT,
    TYPE_DOUBLE,
    TYPE_INVALID
};

enum datatype findtype(const char *s)
{
    char *eptr;
    double d;
    double diff;

    errno = 0;

    d = strtod(s, &eptr);
    if ((d == 0 && eptr == s) || errno == ERANGE)
        return TYPE_INVALID;

    diff = d - floor(d+0.5);
    if (d <= INT_MAX && d >= INT_MIN && diff <= F_EPS)
        return TYPE_INT;

    if (d <= LONG_MAX && d >= LONG_MIN && diff <= F_EPS)
        return TYPE_LONG;

    if ((d > 0 && (d > FLT_MAX || d < FLT_MIN))
                || (d < 0 && (d < -FLT_MAX || d > -FLT_MIN)))
        return TYPE_FLOAT;

    return TYPE_DOUBLE;
}
```

The idea is that you read the number as a `double`, and then check to see if it is in the range for different types.  You can change `F_EPS` above to control the tolerance.