# How can I reject an alphanumeric command-line argument (i.e. ./main 20x), but not a solely numeric one (i.e. ./main 20)? (in C)

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, cs50

I have figured out how to reject a purely alphabetical argument. I cannot figure out how to reject an alphanumeric user input while passing numeric inputs.

Here is my relevant code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || isalpha(*argv[1]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    else...
```

and my code goes on to successfully carry out the function of my program (save for this one bug).

Any help would be much appreciated! This is for an edX cs50 homework assignment. I finished the whole assignment except for this bug. I searched for an answer for over 3 hours, to no avail. Help me, stack overflownobi. You're my only hope.

Comment: What about `int isalnum(int x);` . See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isalnum-function-c-language/

Comment: You're *parsing* the string to an integer, right? then why not use a recipe for *that*?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024648/convert-a-string-to-int-but-only-if-really-is-an-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there: your code checks if `*argv[1]` (i.e. the first character of that argument) is an alphabetic character. Instead, let's use a loop to check the entire `argv[1]` string. We're also going to use `isdigit` instead, so that we can reject strings such as `41!@4` which wouldn't get detected using `isalpha`.

`argv` is an array of `char*`, or pointers to characters, meaning that `argv[1]` is a pointer to the first character of that argument. Given a pointer to the first character of a string, we need to find the string's length using `strlen`, after which we can write a loop. Let's break this out into a function:

```
bool string_is_numeric(char* string) {
    size_t length = strlen(string);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(!isdigit(string[i])) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can call this as follows:

```
if (argc != 2 || !string_is_numeric(*argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Note that the code I gave has a few limitations:

1. It doesn't check whether the number is too large, e.g. to fit into an `int`.
2. It doesn't handle decimal values (i.e. those that we would parse into `double`).
3. It doesn't allow negative numbers.

### Alternative using `strtol`:

The library function `strtol` allows you to convert your string to a `long int`, while also providing you a pointer to the very first character that couldn't be converted.

You can check that pointer: if it points to a null character (i.e. `*endptr == '\0'`), then `strtol` reached the end of the string successfully meaning that it was all valid digits.

You'll need to declare a `long` and a `char*` to hold the results:

```
if (argc != 2)
{
   printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
   return 1;
}
char* endptr;
long key = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10); // 10 meaning decimal
if(*endptr != '\0') {
   printf("Key must be numeric and fit into a long\n");
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Could consider using `strtol()` or similar to see whether the string is an integer.  You can check where the converted text ends and object if there are unwanted characters after the conversion finishes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my intent was to present an iteration on the OP's existing approach which would be pedagogically informative. I'll update with the library-based approach when not on a mobile device.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Judging by others' responses, I'm guessing there was redundancy in your explanation, although it certainly helped in a pedagogical sense. Would using strtol() be a more elegant/concise solution? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @dayvista I'd agree that `strtol` makes sense. I'm writing an update now

Comment: Note that `strtol` also requires checking `errno` in an unusual way; see [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) for details. *And*, if the type you want isn't exactly `long`, you need to do a bounds check of your own afterward.

Comment: @dayvista Using `strtol` is not concise; you must check a few conditions. The main advantage is that it will catch the out of range error, though it is not clear from your question you want that.

Comment: thanks for the update @ReinstateMonica-ζ--. It luckily turned out that the limitations of your original suggestion fit the function of my program