# Checking if an input is a double using scanf?

Tags: c

I'm reading input from stdin and storing the numbers into an array. I have to exit this reading process if this happens: end of file, any invalid input no recognized by scanf, or if the array is full.

So for the "any invalid input not recognized by scanf" I want to check if the input is a double and if it isn't then it exits the for loop. Can someone explain how to do this? I have read the man page for scanf but I still don't quite understand it.

```
int reading;
double array[1000];

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      reading = scanf("%d", &array[i]);
      if (reading == EOF) {
         break;
      }
}
```

Comment: %d is not a double, it's a decimal. You want %f for floating point.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997587/function-to-check-if-input-is-int-or-floating-pt-number

Comment: scanf function can't validate the input,you may use `getline` and check the input yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use correct conversion and check `scanf()` result

```
int reading = scanf("%lf", &array[i]);
// If there is no input ...  (stdin is closed or I/O error, rare but possible)
if (reading == EOF) {
  break;
}
// Some input was available, but did not make sense for a double.
else if (reading == 0) {
  // The data is still in the input buffer and needs to be read before trying to read a double again.
  break;
}
// Input is good
else if (reading == 1) {
  break;
}
// Should never get here
else {
  break;
}
```

---

For robust I/O, I'd recommend using fgets()/sscanf() instead.

```
char buffer[40];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) handle_EOF_or_IO_Error();
if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &array[i]) != 1) handle_unexpected_text_error();
```